# Retrofit LED pot lights without housing, is it safe?

Tags: electrical, recessed-lighting

We’re replacing old can pot lights (the ones with bulbs). [photo of old fixture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu0oO.jpg)

The new slim retrofit led pot lights do not fit into the metal housing so we’ve removed it. [photo of metal can removal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngsfj.jpg). They can be mounted without the housing and they stay in place. Is it safe to leave them without the metal can housing? [Photo of the new retrofit led lights installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCHC6.jpg) . Do I need to somehow house these wires? These are the exact connections [Retrofit wires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wlxS.jpg) , there are no live wires or round splices, is this safe? Edit to add: there is no insulation and it’s on the main floor, there is a level above and the led lights are airtight models

[photo of fixture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlKaP.jpg)

Comment: This depends on the retrofit fixture. Some are designed and listed for operation without a "can" others are not so the can is needed. What do the retrofit fixture instructions say?

Comment: Does the new fixture have a mark such as UL, ETL, CSA?  Or is the dominant mark CE or CCC?

Comment: Thanks! It says IC rated (suitable for direct contact with insulation) but it also says that use only in open luminaries and recessed luminaires where the led light fits. The original metal can housing is why 1/4 inch for it to fit

Comment: For future reference, it makes everyone's life _much_ easier if you upload your pictures as part of creating your question instead of pre-loading them to imgur and posting the links here. SE has a deal that imgur hosts the images, but they're easier to embed instead of requiring clicking links and opening tabs to see the images.

Comment: Based on the connectors in "Retrofit Wires", it looks like you're supposed to install the new light into the old can by screwing it into the bulb socket, connecting the pig tails at the orange connectors, then pushing the new "puck" into the old can. Or does the new can come with a socket base that you have to wire into the house wiring?

Comment: run it for an hour, touch the casing. if it burns you, you should use a can. if not, it's fine, safety-wise.